# Vanish Plugin Minecraft

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft

I have made a vanish plugin but I'm having trouble with making it so server admins can see the person when they are in vanish. I want to make it so if they have permission they can see people in vanish.

```
public class VanishCommand implements CommandExecutor {

    VanishPlugin plugin;

    public VanishCommand(VanishPlugin plugin) {
        this.plugin = plugin;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args) {

        Player p = (Player) sender;

        if (p.hasPermission("vanish.vanish")) {

            if (sender instanceof Player) {
                Player player = (Player) sender;
                if (plugin.invisible_list.contains(player)) {
                    for (Player people : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
                        people.showPlayer(plugin, player);
                    }
                    plugin.invisible_list.remove(player);
                    player.sendMessage("§cYou Are Now Un Vanished§r");
                } else if (!plugin.invisible_list.contains(player)) {
                    for (Player people : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
                        people.hidePlayer(plugin, player);
                    }
                    plugin.invisible_list.add(player);
                    player.sendMessage("§aYou Are Now Vanished!§r");

                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    for (Player people : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
                    people.hidePlayer(plugin, player);
                }
```

this code snippet is the problem. You have to add a if query if the other player have the permissions to see the player. As example the following code:

```
    for (Player people : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
                    if(!people.hasPermission("xyz.vanish"){
                    people.hidePlayer(plugin, player);
                }
}
```